# Django - How do i check whether a date has expired inside filter condition

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

How do i check whether a date has expired or not with respect to today in filter condition.
eg:

```
task = Task.objects.filter(job=obj, status__in = ["in-progress","assigned"],Q(to_be_completed_by_date_until__gte =datetime.now())
```

This results in error, I  want to know how `to_be_completed_by_date` has to be handled so that it will give the results `to_be_completed_by_date<datetime.now()` is True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `Q` here. simply put this

```
task = Task.objects.filter(job=obj, status__in=["in-progress","assigned"], to_be_completed_by_date_until__gte=datetime.now())
```

Comment: is this field name? to_be_completed_by_date_until

Comment: yes it is the field name @reza_khalafi

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
present = datetime.now()
task = Task.objects.filter(job=obj, status__in=["in-progress","assigned"], YOUR_DATETIME_FIELD_NAME__gte=present)
```

that's clear.